# Wordpress: possible to use blog title when there is no search term?

Tags: php, wordpress, search, replace

In Wordpress I currently get the search time like so:

```
<?php $kw = str_replace("-"," ", $_GET['s']);
```

however, I would like it so that if there is no search term, the site title is used for $kw instead.

How best to achieve this?  I have played around with get_bloginfo(); but no success.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a filter to the get_search_query function and intercept the incoming query. if the query is empty use the site title else proceed as planned. see the code below (to be added to your functions.php file in your theme)

```
<?php
  function my_search_query($query) {
    $blog_title = get_bloginfo();
    $query = (empty($query) ? $blog_title : str_replace("-", " ",$query);

    return $query;
  }

  apply_filters( "get_search_query", "my_search_query" );
?>
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you very much.  I have tried adding your code (minus php tags) but I get the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

Thanks for any further help.

Comment: I was missing a semicolon at the end of apply_filters functions and have edited my answer. try it again